# How to store ranges in array, collection, or dictionary based on criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to parse through a contiguous range of data (orng) and create subranges from orng that contain the same string value in the 6th column of orng. Each subrange has 1-15 rows and 38 columns. As far as I know, I can't create a new range object for each subrange since the number of subranges is unknown. I've created an array that contains the data for the subranges (aData). I have gotten it to work with the code below, but I feel like there is a much cleaner way of doing it that I can't figure out. I've also tried using a dictionary with no success. I will eventually have to call upon all the data for calculations and using multiple nested for loops to access each element seems convoluted.

I am using Excel Professional Plus 2016 (not sure if that matters).

Using an array is the only way I could manage to get the end result I'm looking for, which is fine. I would prefer that the array was dynamic, but whenever I attempted the ReDim Preserve method the values would not be saved to the array. The size of the array would be perfect, but every element was "Empty". According to [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/can-t-assign-to-an-array) "each element of an array must have its value assigned individually" so I guess I can't assign range values to an array in chunks. After I found that webpage I implemented an array with a predetermined structure and the nested for loops.

Ideally, I could separate orng into different Areas, but since it is contiguous I am unable to do so. What I'd like to know is 1) is there a better way to do what I am trying to do? (Easier to read, faster, less code, etc. and 2) if there is not a better way, can I get some advice on how to make this code cleaner (dynamic range, less loops, better structure)?

```
Private Sub rangetest()

Dim twb As Workbook: Set twb = ThisWorkbook
Dim cws As Worksheet: Set cws = twb.Sheets("Cleaned_2019+")
Dim orng As Range
Dim datelot As String, datelotcomp As String
Dim c As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, numrows As Long, lastrow 
    As Long, numlots As Long, _
    curRow As Long, lotRows As Long, startRow As Long, layerRows As Long, 
    aRow As Long
Dim aLot() As Variant, aData(9, 49, 37) As Variant
Dim Z As Boolean

Set orng = cws.Range("A973:AL1014")   'Set initial range to work with.
numrows = orng.Rows.Count             'Number of rows in orng.
curRow = 1                            'Current row in orng.
startRow = 1                          'Starting row in orng for next 
layer (changes when lot changes).
i = 0                                 'Layer of array (for aLot and aData arrays).
j = 0                                 'Row in orng where values for previous layer ended.
Z = False
Do Until Z = True
    datelot = Left(orng.Cells(curRow, 6).Value, 10)                            'Lot that we want the data for. Corresponds to a layer in the aData array.
    datelotcomp = Left(orng.Cells(curRow + 1, 6).Value, 10)                    'Lot of the next row in data sheet.
    If datelot <> datelotcomp Then                                             'If datelotcomp <> to datelot then we want a new layer for array.
        layerRows = curRow - j                                                 'Number of rows for a particular layer
        ReDim Preserve aLot(i)                                                 'Array of lot names
        aLot(i) = datelot                                                      'Assign lot name to aLot array
        For aRow = 1 To layerRows                                              'Row index in array
            For lotRows = startRow To curRow                                   'Loops through orng rows and sets those values in array
                For c = 1 To 38                                                'Loops through columns. There are always 38 columns
                    aData(i, aRow - 1, c - 1) = orng.Cells(lotRows, c).Value   'Add values to each index in array
                Next c
            Next lotRows
        Next aRow
        j = curRow
        i = i + 1
        startRow = curRow + 1
    End If
    If curRow = numrows Then                                                   'End loop at end of orng
        Z = True
    End If
    curRow = curRow + 1
Loop
numlots = i

End Sub
```

The result I get is an array with the structure aData(9, 49, 37) that contains data in the first 4 layers aData(1-3, , ). This corresponds with the number of lots that are in orng so the code is working correctly. I'd just like advice on if I'm doing anything inefficiently.

I will be checking back to answer questions or to add clarification.

Edit 1:

The question ended up being answered [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/223897/store-subranges-from-contiguous-range-into-array-based-on-criteria/223912#223912) (Code Review) for those interested.

Comment: If your code is working and you just want efficiency, it's better suit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Cyril Please see [_Migration of code questions from Stack Overflow to Code Review_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266749/1575353) and [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ thanks; i used the wrong close reason on that one.  Removed above question.  Given the criteria in the latter link, I would stick with this being more appropriate in CR than SO.

Comment: Thank you dwirony for the direction. My mistake!